# How can I change row and column indexes of a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I have a dataframe in R which has three columns Product_Name(name of books), Year and Units (number of units sold in that year) which looks like this:

```
Product_Name            Year     Units
A Modest Proposal       2011     10000
A Modest Proposal       2012     11000
A Modest Proposal       2013     12000
A Modest Proposal       2014     13000
Animal Farm             2011     8000 
Animal Farm             2012     9000
Animal Farm             2013     11000
Animal Farm             2014     15000
Catch 22                2011     1000
Catch 22                2012     2000
Catch 22                2013     3000
Catch 22                2014     4000
....
```

I intend to make a R Shiny dashboard with that where I want to keep the year as a drop-down menu option, for which I wanted to have the dataframe in the following format

```
       A Modest Proposal   Animal Farm  Catch 22 
2011    10000               8000         1000
2012    11000               9000         2000
2013    12000               11000        3000
2014    13000               15000        4000
```

or the other way round where the Product Names are row indexes and Years are column indexes, either way goes.

How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your general issue is transforming long data to wide data. For this, you can use `data.table`'s `dcast` function (amongst many others):

```
dt = data.table(
  Name = c(rep('A', 4), rep('B', 4), rep('C', 4)),
  Year = c(rep(2011:2014, 3)), 
  Units = rnorm(12)
)

> dt
    Name Year       Units
 1:    A 2011 -0.26861318
 2:    A 2012  0.27194732
 3:    A 2013 -0.39331361
 4:    A 2014  0.58200101
 5:    B 2011  0.09885381
 6:    B 2012 -0.13786098
 7:    B 2013  0.03778400
 8:    B 2014  0.02576433
 9:    C 2011 -0.86682584
10:    C 2012 -1.34319590
11:    C 2013  0.10012673
12:    C 2014 -0.42956207


> dcast(dt, Year ~ Name, value.var = 'Units')
   Year          A           B          C
1: 2011 -0.2686132  0.09885381 -0.8668258
2: 2012  0.2719473 -0.13786098 -1.3431959
3: 2013 -0.3933136  0.03778400  0.1001267
4: 2014  0.5820010  0.02576433 -0.4295621
```

For the next time, it is easier if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that the people assisting you do not have to manually recreate your data structure :)

Comment: Thank you so much. This works. Actually this whole thing was in my work laptop, so I can't really transfer stuff from there to my personal laptop (where Im posting this query from). Also I had no idea how to create a reproducible example. Thanks for the link to help out with that as well

Answer (score 1):

You need to use pivot_wider from tidyr package. I assumed your data is saved in df and you also need dplyr package for %>% (piping)

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Product_Name, values_from = Units)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your dataframe is ordered by Product_Name and by year, I will generate artificial data similar to your datafrme, try this:

```
Col_1 <- sort(rep(LETTERS[1:3], 4))
Col_2 <- rep(2011:2014, 3)
# artificial data
resp <- ceiling(rnorm(12, 5000, 500))

uu <- data.frame(Col_1, Col_2, resp)
uu
# output is
   Col_1 Col_2 resp
1      A  2011 5297
2      A  2012 4963
3      A  2013 4369
4      A  2014 4278
5      B  2011 4721
6      B  2012 5021
7      B  2013 4118
8      B  2014 5262
9      C  2011 4601
10     C  2012 5013
11     C  2013 5707
12     C  2014 5637
> 
> # Here starts
> output <- aggregate(uu$resp, list(uu$Col_1), function(x) {x})
> output
  Group.1  x.1  x.2  x.3  x.4
1       A 5297 4963 4369 4278
2       B 4721 5021 4118 5262
3       C 4601 5013 5707 5637
> 
output2 <- output [, -1]
colnames(output2) <- levels(as.factor(uu$Col_2))
rownames(output2) <- levels(as.factor(uu$Col_1))

# transpose the matrix
> t(output2)
        A    B    C
2011 5297 4721 4601
2012 4963 5021 5013
2013 4369 4118 5707
2014 4278 5262 5637
> # or convert to data.frame
> as.data.frame(t(output2))
        A    B    C
2011 5297 4721 4601
2012 4963 5021 5013
2013 4369 4118 5707
2014 4278 5262 5637
```